# Order by Month name and by Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to order month name like Jan, Feb, march, April...till DEC and am getting this by using
`datepart(m,Time)` but I have data from 2012 and 2013. It shows data Jan 2012, Jan 2013, Feb 2012, Feb 2013 but I wan to order the Year also so that all 2012 data should come first and then 2013 data.

Comment: Please post your current query

Comment: **[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)**

Comment: **Have any of us helped?**

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial solution to a partial question, but generally you would use:

`ORDER BY YEAR(TimeColumn), DATEPART(m, TimeColumn)`

Comment: I have tried this but still it gives me Jan 2012 , Jan 2013 , Feb 2012 and Feb 2013

Comment: If I first Put Year(time) and then datepart(m, time) it orders by year means all 2012 data is coming first but month names are not in order

Comment: In your question, please add some sample data and the code you are using.

Comment: declare startdate datetime='1/1/2012',enddate datetime='2/1/2013'
select DATENAME(m, time1)
 + DATENAME(YEAR, time1)as times
from table1
where time1.start between startdate and enddate
order by DATEPART(M, time1), YEAR(time1)   nd output coming:January2012
January2013
February2012

Comment: OK, the ORDER in the `ORDER BY` is important.  Put the code exactly as written, with `YEAR()` **FIRST**

Comment: Yeah but this arrange the data by year but month are not in order

Comment: You can have the `SELECT` in a different order than the `ORDER BY` - this is really a simple issue and I'm not sure why you are complicating it.

Comment: am not getting this thats why have posted question here....anywayz ur ways is not solving my problem ...thanks anywayz

Comment: @SQllearner Again, if you post sample data and your query into the body of your question you are more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY DatePart(y,time),DatePart(m,time)
```

Comment: I have tried this but still it gives me Jan 2012 , Jan 2013 , Feb 2012 and Feb 2013

Answer (score 0):

Repeating what has already been said

```
SELECT '01 jan 2012' AS Dt INTO #tempDates
UNION
SELECT '01 jun 2012'
UNION
SELECT '10 oct 2012'
UNION
SELECT '01 jan 2013'

--1
SELECT Dt
FROM #tempDates
ORDER BY DatePart(YY,Dt),DatePart(m,Dt)

--2
SELECT Dt
FROM #tempDates
ORDER BY YEAR(Dt), MONTH(Dt)

--3
SELECT Dt
FROM #tempDates
ORDER BY YEAR(Dt), DatePart(m,Dt)
```